# Center vertically radiobutton and it's label

Tags: html, css

I have such code:

```
<form method="post" id="sc_form">        
     <div class="radio-group">     
          <input type="radio" name="phone" id="send" value="send"></input>
          <label for="send">Вы отправитель</label>
     </div>
     <div class="radio-group">
          <input type="radio" name="phone" id="get" value="get"></input>
          <label for="get">Вы получатель</label>
     </div>  
     <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить" id="send-button" />
</form>
```

css:

```
#get, #send{
  border: none;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline;
}

.radio-group{
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 10px 6px 10px;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Garuda,sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

input[type='radio'], label{   
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

and I want to set-up radio and label on same line, so that they will look beautiful, and be centered vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zn93w/

Whole page and css: http://jsfiddle.net/2yZTK/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this work for me

```
input[type='radio']{
    margin:0;
}

input[type='radio'], label{   
   display:inline;
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

Удачи )

Comment: It make sense to add class `.radio` to radio buttons and change your `input[type='radio']` selector to be `input[type='radio'], .radio` so browsers that do not understand attribute css selectors will still have labels aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Driveash/Zn93w/1/

I added line-height in .radio-group class and changed vertical align by input and label.

```
.radio-group{
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 10px 6px 10px;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Garuda,sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height:11px;
}

input[type='radio'], label{   
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: 0; //for the whole site.
}
```

Comment: `margin: 0;` really does the trick in input[type='radio'], label. As @Alexandre Diacov suggested.